# track changes in associated tables, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, I need to track the changes made to an attribute. I've used "object.changes" to find the changes. However, this does not produce the changes made to fields of associated tables. So how can I track the changes made to the associated tables?
I've a customer table which holds the id and the address and a discount table which holds the discount rate for that customer. Whenever I change the Customer address I can get it. But the changes I make to the discount rate is not recorded.

Comment: Use [`ActiveRecord::Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to listen for changes on a model from any other model.

Comment: Can you give us some more context?

Comment: You might look for inspriation in [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) and the Railscasts linked [on Plugingeek](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/activity-tracking-ruby).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a separate module, which on included into model will track its changes.  [link](http://pjkh.com/articles/creating-an-audit-log-in-rails/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, firstly thank you for taking the time to answer. Please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here, read [answer] to create helpful answers and add to the community. Even though this is a accepted question, include code samples in the answer, because links can become broken over time.